# How many Memory Cards are used with both "Tea Dragon Society" and "Autumn Harvest" card games?

Tags: the-tea-dragon-society-card-games

We recently received both "The Tea Dragon Society Card Game" and "Autumn Harvest: A Tea Dragon Society Card Game" for the holidays, and we read that the games can be combined and played together.

We want to play with both games combined, but we are unsure of how to set up the Memory Tableau (Memory Card Deck) for a combined game set up.

The "Tea Dragon Society" was made first and does not reference "Autumn Harvest" in its instructions. The instructions for "Autumn Harvest" say this about how to combine the two games:

> **Playing With More Dragons**
>
> There are eight cards contained in this box for use with the original "The Tea Dragon Society Card Game".
>
> [...]
>
> These eight cards allow players to combine both "Tea Dragon Society Card Games" with the Dragons being balanced for play among the full array of Market and Memory cards. This will also allow games with up to 5 players

The phrase "for play among the full array of Market and Memory cards" reads as if you can combine *all* Memory cards for both games together.

The reason for our confusion is that the game setup section for "Autumn Harvest" only specifies removing Memory cards for the base game, and not the combined game. For example, it says to remove 2 cards per season with 2-3 players (4 cards total), and to remove 1 card per 4-5 players (5 cards total).

Reading this literally for the combined game Memory deck, this would mean that we would remove  remove 2 cards per season with 2-3 players (10 cards total), and remove 1 card per 4-5 players (11 cards total). There are no other instructions about how to combine Memory cards when playing with both games. This doesn't seem right, because you need use up the Memory cards to proceed through seasons to progress the game; this would add *a lot* of play time to the game if you had to go through more than twice the number of cards per season.

Has this been clarified anywhere? Do you combine decks to get 12 cards and then only take 6 of them and remove according to the instructions (similar to the base game set up)? Or do you combine both decks and remove normally, and have 6 more Memory cards with the combined game (base game setup + 6 memory cards)?

A link to the "Autumn Harvest" instructions can be found here: [Instructions for "Autumn Harvest"](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54148cdae4b05a3412bfa19b/t/5fb40e66b45d862c6ce070e9/1605635689163/Autumn+Harvest+Rulebook.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to the Boardgames stack exchange, I've updated the tag for your question to a new one.

Answer (score 1):

A question about combining has been asked [on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2555689/confused-about-combining) and the designer, Steve Ellis, answered as follows.

> Please feel free to mix and match Memory cards as long as you use
> select the appropriate number for your player count as referenced in
> the Autumn Harvest setup. For the Market cards, shuffling these all
> together is perfectly acceptable or you can customize the Market deck
> as you see fit with cards from one or both games as you desire.

Comment: This quote is still a little unclear because the original `Autumn Harvest` game doesn't explicitly say how many cards to start with, only how many to remove. We are assuming this means "Start with 6 per season, and remove accordingly" since that is how many came with each season in the original game. The instructions, however are written to say "For each game, have `x`-2 or `x`-1 cards based on number of players" but it never actually specifies  what `x` is.

Comment: "The game ends when only one Memory card remains in the Winter season".  Do you think the purpose of the mixing the sets is to make the game longer?      both sets come with "24 Memory cards (6 cards each for spring,
fall, winter, and summer".   I think its reasonable to assume that X = 6 unless you think the game should be longer.